# Solving equations over the complex numbers field

Tags: complex-numbers

$z^6=(1+i4\sqrt{3})^3$
I have found solutions of this equation: $z^2=1+i4\sqrt{3}$

they are the following: $z_0=\pm2\pm i\sqrt{3}$ 
Now, hence i want to find the remaining solutions of the equation.
I the exercise i have a hint to multiply both sides of equation by $z_0^{-6}$ but still i do not understand how this could help in finding solutions of the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(zz_0^{-1})^6=1$ you know that $zz_0^{-1}$ is a sixth root of $1$, that is,
$$zz_0^{-1}=e^{k\pi i/3}$$
or
$$z=z_0e^{k\pi i/3}$$
for $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Now you can obtain $z$ for each $k$ in that set.

**Note**: the sixth roots of unity are given by:
$$e^{2k\pi i/6}=e^{k\pi i/3}$$

Comment: $zz_0^{-1}=e^{k\pi i/3}$  where does this division by three comes from?